# How to solve error Call to a member function isReadonly() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I am trying to display product grid on my custome page in admin panel. 
Product grid is working fine. Here is the code:

```
<sliders_adminhtml_sliders_index>
        <update handle="sliders_myform_index"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_grid" name="sliders" />
        </reference>
    </sliders_adminhtml_sliders_index>
```

But when I want to edit the prodcut I get error **"Call to a member function isReadonly() on a non-object"**

Here is how I trying to create edit page:

```
<sliders_adminhtml_sliders_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-"></block>
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</sliders_adminhtml_sliders_edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info where exactly this error appears.

In general code for product edit layout looks like this:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-"></block>
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

So I'd suggest to add `<update handle="editor"/>` firstly. Maybe some references to objects in `left` are causing that error (you need to try or provide more info).

And I'm sure you will need to add `js` part too.

Comment: Hello, Taras. This error i saw in log file. I put your code to my layout file but this error is not going away. I've updated my question.

Comment: [Sat Jan 11 19:04:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isReadonly() on a non-object in /var/www/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php on line 75, referer: http://sitename/index.php/sliders/adminhtml_sliders/index/key/da7495b435fe3a88d3025a04b9e5d42d/

Comment: `if (!$this->getProduct()->isReadonly())` is on line 75, right? And `public function getProduct() { return Mage::registry('current_product'); }` then. So you need to set `current_product` in you controller.